# Dynamically loading JPEG images with require in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, image

I'm trying to dynamically load JPEG images in my React Native app using the require function. However, I'm encountering an issue where the required call throws an error. Here's the relevant code:

```
javascript
const StoriesView = ({ stories }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.storiesScrollView}>
      <View style={styles.storiesContainer}>
        {stories.map((name, index) => (
          <Image
            key={index}
            style={styles.storyImage}
            source={require(`./assets/${name}.jpg`)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

> App.js:Invalid call at line 85: require("./assets/" + name + ".jpg")

I have verified that the assets folder exists in the root directory of my project, and the file names in the stories array match the actual image file names.
Am I using the require function correctly for loading JPEG images? Is there something I'm missing or a different approach I should take?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Native, the require() function used for image loading only accepts a static string as its argument. It does not support dynamic or variable paths, which is why you are getting that error.

To dynamically load images in React Native, you can use the `uri` property of the Image component instead of `require()`. Here's what that would look like:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

const StoriesView = ({ stories }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView horizontal showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.storiesScrollView}>
      <View style={styles.storiesContainer}>
        {stories.map((name, index) => (
          <Image
            key={index}
            style={styles.storyImage}
            source={{ uri: `./assets/${name}.jpg` }}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

With this change, you're using the uri prop and providing a string that represents the path to your image file. Might be good to chek the paths in your stories array are correct.